# Exchanging integral and transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings, integral-extensions

Let $L$ be an integral extension of the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ of finite type, is there a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $L$ embeds into $K[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}[x,\sqrt{x^3+x}]$ doesn't embed into $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

Comment: @reuns is this easy to see? Is it somehow related to algebraic points on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + x$?

Comment: Do you know that every subfield $K\subsetneq F \subset K(y)$ is such that $F=K(z)$? Next, composing with $x_i\mapsto a_i+b_i y$, an embedding into $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ gives an embedding into $K[y]$. Overall $K(t,\sqrt{t^3+t})\cong K(z)$ which is a contradiction.